# How do I open the Dahl chest in Sanctuary?

Tags: borderlands-2

In the house with Tannis and the Safe in Sanctuary (the Crimson Raider hideout) there's a red Dahl branded chest behind a gate. There's a green-lit switch to the left of the door but pulling it doesn't work. Later on in the story the switch turns red and won't turn, I still can't get into the gate.

How do I open the gate and get to that chest?

Comment: I might describe this place as the Crimson Raider hideout.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will gain access to the room after completing the main storyline quest **Where Angels Fear to Tread (Part 2)**. You only get to loot the chest once, however.

Answer (score 5):

It opens after a storyline quest, which I'd completed around level 20.  (or ~30 if you do side missions)